# Calculate the slope of a 3D triangle?

Tags: mathematics, javascript, geometry, 3d-meshes

I have lots of triangles in 3D space. How do I determine the slope/angle of these triangles with respect to a fixed ground plane? I need pseudo code examples at the very least.

Comment: What do you mean by “angle”? Are you asking how to calculate a [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry))?

Comment: Maybe he's looking for tangent and bi-tangent

Comment: I'm not looking for a vector. I need the slope of the plane formed by the triangle with respect to the ground plane. The angle between the floating plane and the ground plane will be okay too.

Comment: I guess the angle between the normal and the ground would be okay too. From that I can get the information I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [dnk drone.vs.drones](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/62256/dnk-drone-vs-drones)' instructions I created the following JavaScript:

```
function Get_Angle(vertex_1, vertex_2, vertex_3)
{
    // get two vectors in the triangle
    var vector_u =
    [
        vertex_2[0] - vertex_1[0],
        vertex_2[1] - vertex_1[1],
        vertex_2[2] - vertex_1[2]
    ]
    var vector_v =
    [
        vertex_3[0] - vertex_1[0],
        vertex_3[1] - vertex_1[1],
        vertex_3[2] - vertex_1[2]
    ]
    // calculate the cross product to get the normal
    var vector_n =
    [
        vector_u[1] * vector_v[2] - vector_u[2] * vector_v[1],
        vector_u[2] * vector_v[0] - vector_u[0] * vector_v[2],
        vector_u[0] * vector_v[1] - vector_u[1] * vector_v[0]
    ]
    // calculate the magnitude or length of the normal vector
    var magnitude_n = Math.sqrt(vector_n[0] * vector_n[0] + vector_n[1] * vector_n[1] + vector_n[2] * vector_n[2])
    // normalize the normal vector
    vector_n =
    [
        vector_n[0]/magnitude_n,
        vector_n[1]/magnitude_n,
        vector_n[2]/magnitude_n
    ]
    // the normal of the ground plane
    var vector_r = [0,1,0]
    // calculate the dot product of vector_n and vector_r
    var dot_product = vector_n[0] * vector_r[0] + vector_n[1] * vector_r[1] + vector_n[2] * vector_r[2]
    // calculate the angle between vector_n and vector_r
    var angle_between = Math.acos(dot_product)
    // returned value is less than or equal to pi
    return angle_between
}
```

Comment: Oh wow! Three years later! That's great, thanks for coming back and posting your solution :)

Comment: Can someone confirm this produces accurate results? I'm trying to review slope for rain drainage but I'm getting interesting results using the function above. https://i.imgur.com/RTIK3Fc.png white labels are for confirmed edge grade (deg/90*100 basically) and green labels is for the face grade. Shouldn't the face share the grade of the 2.85% edge since the top edge is at 0%?

Answer (score 4):

EDIT (added short steps):

1. get triangle normal vector `v1` (normalized)
2. get reference surface normal vector `v2` (normalized)
3. get angle between normals : `angle = acos(v1•v2)` (where • = 'dot' product )
4. get `slope = Tan(angle)`

if you need a [surface normal](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Calculating_a_Surface_Normal) here come the simple algoritm :

A surface normal for a triangle can be calculated by taking the vector cross product of two edges of that triangle. The order of the vertices used in the calculation will affect the direction of the normal (in or out of the face w.r.t. winding).

So for a triangle p1, p2, p3, if the vector U = p2 - p1 and the vector V = p3 - p1 then the normal N = U X V and can be calculated by:

Nx = UyVz - UzVy

Ny = UzVx - UxVz

Nz = UxVy - UyVx

EDIT: to get the angle between reference plane and triangle plane , you can calculate the angle between reference plane normal vector (call it Nref) and triangle normal (N already calculated). [Here the angle between 3d vectors math](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/vectors/angleBetween/):

"If v1 and v2 are normalised so that |v1|=|v2|=1, then,

angle = acos(v1•v2)"

Finaly [from angle to slope](https://www.math.washington.edu/~greenber/slope.html) : Tan(angle)

Comment: I need the slope, though. A single scalar value not a vector.

Comment: @posfan12 Angle between the ground plane and a triangle?

Comment: I think you can't define a single slope. You can get x-slope and y-slope , and can calculate them from normal vector x and y components

Comment: Why no slope? Two planes intersect at only one angle.

Comment: oops , you're absolutely right

Comment: answer edited and integrated

Comment: @dnk drone.vs.drones I edited my post with some code but it is not working. Can you see what I did wrong?

Comment: Never mind. I forgot to normalize the cross product. It works now.